# Can we find an invertible, integer matrix with a given first row?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Given $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)=1$, is it possible to find $M \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ with first row $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$?

Clearly for $n=2$ the result is true. For $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $\gcd(a,b)=1$, there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ax+by=1$. Then the required matrix is $
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   -y & x \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$.
But I am not being able to extend it to general case. Even the converse of this result is true. For $M \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ we can prove that every row and column has gcd 1.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76645/can-any-set-of-n-relatively-prime-elements-be-extended-to-an-invertible-matrix where it is noted that there's a relation to the Quillen-Suslin Theorem, aka Serre's Conjecture.

Answer (score 2):

yes. By a finite sequence of elementary, integer matrices (determinant one), we can eventually write the first row as $(1,0,0,0,...,0).$ Call the original row $R,$ we now have $RG = (1,0,0,...,0).$ It follows that the top row of $G^{-1}$ is the original row, while both $G$ and $G^{-1}$ have integer entries